# When I go to install the demo content in the tools and click on Install the template that I uploaded,in wordpris it is not wanted, and I see this sign

Tags: onion-services, help, tor-install, development, network-health

[image]

I want a solution, please. Yesterday I downloaded the template from Team Forest, and I want to install it, but whoever has the situation does not respond, please contact me.

Comment: I don't think this is related to Tor. You might get better help on a Wordpress forum.

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is described in your error logs. It's - most likely - a DRM issue, when it tries to contact any kind of a DRM server to validate your license. But anyway - the **Full** stack trace will show you what's happening